# resume from blank screen nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ] (18.10)

Tags: graphics, suspend, ibus, nouveau, 18.10

On Ubuntu 18.10 I have Settings for `blank screen` after 10 mins however when I hit ESC to resume it just shows purple screen and does not respond to keyboard no login prompt ... using screen top right down arrow I hit Suspend ... then upon resume from suspend I do get login screen and can successfully login

I use an external monitor with Setting  `Single Display`  set to the external monitor.  This same laptop has been stable using latest installs of ubuntu for past 2 years from 16.04 onward ... issue only started when using 18.10

See this in dmesg

```
[27136.550369] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[27211.919725] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[27245.512210] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[27291.984129] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[27478.869535] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[27514.207378] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[27618.231461] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[27642.438778] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[27691.551219] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[27713.345430] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[27823.347331] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[27837.543195] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[28015.555226] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[28043.639116] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[28089.471048] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[28240.502741] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[28275.753334] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[28484.422433] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[28540.522075] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[28600.501367] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[28612.342252] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[28640.935630] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[28669.949796] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[28716.573482] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[28732.869982] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[28828.805236] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[28887.548366] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[28909.273059] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[29038.187785] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[29108.488615] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[29162.420835] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[29271.171928] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[29298.708229] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[29480.555963] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[29505.961750] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[29594.711825] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
```

in addition to above which appears earlier here is most recent `dmesg` which also contains one occurrence of above fault

```
[71038.833600] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 00:23:69:9e:ae:7f by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[71039.487477] PM: suspend entry (deep)
[71039.487481] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[71042.693255] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.389 seconds) done.
[71043.082514] OOM killer disabled.
[71043.082517] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[71043.084961] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[71043.104875] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[71043.106115] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[71044.102133] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[71044.145379] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[71044.148973] ACPI: EC: event blocked
[71044.148975] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
[71044.148976] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[71044.149118] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[71044.164974] IRQ 131: no longer affine to CPU1
[71044.165993] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[71044.188895] IRQ 126: no longer affine to CPU2
[71044.190966] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[71044.212746] IRQ 122: no longer affine to CPU3
[71044.212755] IRQ 125: no longer affine to CPU3
[71044.213783] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[71044.220685] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[71044.220765] ACPI: EC: EC started
[71044.220765] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[71044.223048] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[71044.223201] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[71044.223201] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[71044.223710]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[71044.223804] microcode: sig=0x806e9, pf=0x80, revision=0x38
[71044.225392] CPU1 is up
[71044.225418] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1
[71044.225941]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[71044.226029] microcode: sig=0x806e9, pf=0x80, revision=0x8e
[71044.226177] CPU2 is up
[71044.226202] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
[71044.226689]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[71044.226928] CPU3 is up
[71044.230743] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[71044.241378] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[71044.283381] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[71044.285325] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[71044.572516] usb 1-7: reset full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[71044.848443] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[71045.124496] usb 1-8: reset full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[71045.997486] ish-hid {33AECD58-B679-4E54-9BD9-A04D34F0C226}: [hid-ish]: enum_devices_done OK, num_hid_devices=2
[71046.032444] usb 1-1: reset low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[71046.370134] acpi LNXPOWER:13: Turning OFF
[71046.370329] acpi LNXPOWER:12: Turning OFF
[71046.370516] acpi LNXPOWER:11: Turning OFF
[71046.370704] acpi LNXPOWER:10: Turning OFF
[71046.370889] acpi LNXPOWER:0f: Turning OFF
[71046.371073] acpi LNXPOWER:0e: Turning OFF
[71046.371258] acpi LNXPOWER:0d: Turning OFF
[71046.371444] acpi LNXPOWER:0c: Turning OFF
[71046.371629] acpi LNXPOWER:0b: Turning OFF
[71046.371814] acpi LNXPOWER:0a: Turning OFF
[71046.371998] acpi LNXPOWER:09: Turning OFF
[71046.372210] acpi LNXPOWER:08: Turning OFF
[71046.372394] acpi LNXPOWER:07: Turning OFF
[71046.372578] acpi LNXPOWER:06: Turning OFF
[71046.372769] acpi LNXPOWER:04: Turning OFF
[71046.372956] acpi LNXPOWER:03: Turning OFF
[71046.373142] acpi LNXPOWER:02: Turning OFF
[71046.373326] acpi LNXPOWER:01: Turning OFF
[71046.373511] acpi LNXPOWER:00: Turning OFF
[71046.373630] OOM killer enabled.
[71046.373631] Restarting tasks ... 
[71046.392744] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[71046.399754] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[71046.399756] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[71046.399756] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[71046.399757] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[71046.399757] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[71046.399758] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[71046.417691] done.
[71046.417949] thermal thermal_zone4: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[71046.431077] PM: suspend exit
[71046.529444] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[71046.580170] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[71046.666986] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[71046.902297] usb 1-3: current rate 4500480 is different from the runtime rate 44100
[71046.918097] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[71048.169858] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[71048.400728] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[71048.401727] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1973704 usecs
[71048.401760] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[71048.413748] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11713 usecs
[71048.414332] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[71048.417735] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[71048.432515] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[71048.637197] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[71052.606496] wlp2s0: authenticate with 00:23:69:9e:ae:7f
[71052.615166] wlp2s0: send auth to 00:23:69:9e:ae:7f (try 1/3)
[71052.624170] wlp2s0: authenticated
[71052.624320] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[71052.624322] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[71052.628096] wlp2s0: associate with 00:23:69:9e:ae:7f (try 1/3)
[71052.630561] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 00:23:69:9e:ae:7f (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[71052.632915] wlp2s0: associated
[71052.654931] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
```

I do have an Nvidia card however on this install I have not touched the graphics drivers

Asus - Q524UQ Laptop - Intel Core i7 - 12GB Memory - NVIDIA GeForce 940MX          Intel HD Graphics 620

```
uname -a
Linux axo 4.18.0-10-generic #11-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 11 15:13:55 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I would use the proprietary drivers instead.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the newer `Nouveau` drivers aren't compatible with your hardware (common with reverse-engineered drivers from time to time).

- Try removing them (and using only Intel drivers)
- using the NVidia Proprietary drivers
- See if there's some support for NVidia Optimus with your system. I haven't had to mess with this in a while, but there was a "Bumblebee" tool that might be useful.

Comment: i'm have the same error `bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]` trying set up the hibernate. could you pls elaborate, how to 1) remove nouveau, 2) using nvidia driver?

Comment: You'd have some luck here on the Ubuntu wiki - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

In later versions of Ubuntu the drivers are a package in Restricted. In 19.04 you can specify them to be installed at install time. I don't have any Nvidia hardware so I'm a bit at a loss, sorry. I've had such problems with the hardware that I stopped buying them.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar issue with ASUS Vivobook along with ubuntu 22.04. I visited the link described in the previous comment; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia, and I went to the section: Installation without X / from the console. So this is what I did:
I used this command:
`sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`
Within the results I found, I installed this driver:
`sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-515`

So far the screen is working perfectly.